# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch-5

I get an error that I can't resolve. Help appreciated. 
See pictures below.

[image: JS code]

[image: JS Error]

Thanks!

Added info from debug:
`Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined"
stack
:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined↵    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/main.js:7:36), <anonymous>:1:15)↵    at http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/main.js:7:36↵    at Object.execCb (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:1650:33)↵    at Module.check (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:866:51)↵    at Module.<anonymous> (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:1113:34)↵    at http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:132:23↵    at http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:1156:21↵    at each (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:57:31)↵    at Module.emit (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:1155:17)↵    at Module.check (http://192.168.10.151:8000/scripts/require.js:917:30)`

Comment: That means `elasticsearch` is not defined... check your Dev Console's (F12) Network tab for loading errors. Put a break point before that line, and see what variable ARE defined at that point in the code.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the arguments you need to pass for the client method. Check this out : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html
Also add the line "var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');" before you create a new client

Comment: Thanks. I tried loaded the debugger but got fairly little info. Also added the line Aditya suggested. Got: `Uncaught Error: Module name "elasticsearch" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded`
With the debugger I got some more:

Comment: This solved the problem:
`define(['scripts/d3.v3', 'scripts/elasticsearch'], function (d3, es) {

    "use strict";  

    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
     host: 'http://192.168.10.151:9200'
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with the debugger as @SteveR suggested, I finally found a hint that led me to elastiseach.js and the following:

```
    // In order to help people who were accidentally upgraded to this ES client,
    // throw an error when they try to instanciate the exported function.
    // previous "elasticsearch" module -> https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-es
    function es() {
      throw new Error('Looks like you are expecting the previous "elasticsearch" module. '
    +
        'It is now the "es" module. To create a client with this module use' +
        '`new es.Client(params)`.');
    }

    es.Client = __webpack_require__(1);
    es.ConnectionPool = __webpack_require__(33);
    es.Transport = __webpack_require__(2);
    es.errors = __webpack_require__(17);

    module.exports = es;
```

Fixing my code  accordingly:

`define(['scripts/d3.v3', 'scripts/elasticsearch'], function (d3, es) { 
        "use strict"; 
        var client = new elasticsearch.Client({ 
            host: 'http://192.168.10.151:9200' 
        });
    // your code
    }`